# HTML String in Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

How do we pass a valid HTML String into html2canvas?

e.g

```
var html = "<html><head></head><body><p>HI</p></body></html>
```

The way it is done on http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

Html2canvas is really great and all but it's very poorly documented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do as following

```
var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
$('body').append($(iframe));
setTimeout(function(){
    var iframedoc=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document;
    $('body',$(iframedoc)).html('<html><head></head><body><p>HI</p></body></html>');
    html2canvas(iframedoc.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $('body',$(document)).append(canvas);
            $('body',$(document)).remove(iframe);
        }
    });
}, 10);
```

See the whole code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/9v8qb/21/) :

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/9v8qb/21/)

Comment: i update this DEMO link today, since CDN htm2canvas.js became down.. so i add anthoer link for html2canvas.js

Comment: Do you have any idea, what can i do if i won't to put html in document(even hidden)

Answer (score 13):

Usually html2canvas renders DOM elements and not html code. But you can create a temporary iFrame, let your html render in that iFrame, and then give the generated DOM to html2canvas.

You find an example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEMsq/4/) to play around, or here for your convenience:

```
var html_string = "<html><head></head><body><p>HI</p></body></html>";
var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
setTimeout(function(){
    var iframedoc=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframedoc.body.innerHTML=html_string;
    html2canvas(iframedoc.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            document.body.removeChild(iframe);
        }
    });
}, 10);
```

Comment: receiving an error (defaultView is null) on passing iframedoc.body to html2canvas().